# Regex random number in google tag manager

Tags: regex, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use regex within google tag manager(GTM) to see if there is a match on a random number. In this way we can use sampling on certain tags. Only problem, the regex within GTM looks like it has a mind of it own. Simple example.

Google tag manager generates the following number on the gtm.load event: 112677907
My regex(on that same event) looks like follows:
matches RegEx `01$|02$|03$|04$|05$|06$|07$|08$|09$|10$|11$|12$|13$|14$`

Surely this needs to have a match. GTM thinks otherwise... Does anyone have clue?

Comment: Well, too many `|`s? Try `(0[1-9]|1[0-4])$`. Is the pattern anchored by default? Try `.*(0[1-9]|1[0-4])$`.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but made the regex less complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw what was going wrong. In the debugger of GTM you can see the value of you're variables. Though it looks te random number als get triggered in the tag itself. So I was actually looking at the wrong variable. So the RegEx was working fine.